# Help: Euclid's proof of the existence of infinitely many primes.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

Can someone explain [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbizr.png) line at the end. That $k$ is most likely mistaken for $a$, but how does $ (k-b)p_i = 1 $ imply $ p_i = \pm 1 $, that I do not understand.
Also, I am asking this here because I feel this is tied to the material: The fact that addition, subtraction, multiplication of integers always yield integers, is it an axiom? Or does it follow from some other axiom? The book at hand is on real analysis and while it gave quite a sufficient explanation of fields, it had no say on this particular matter (likely not on later chapters either). If I can get by without reading a separate book on algebra tho, for now I'd like to do so.

Comment: It depends, if you define addition on integers, then it yields integers by definition. But since this is a real analysis book, it probably defined addition on real numbers. So you need to prove that the sum of integers yield integers.

Comment: @Trebor So an operation being defined everywhere on $S$ *means* using that operation on elements of $S$ will always yield an element of $S$?

Comment: Nope, but in this case it is often true, as most books either define $+: Z \times Z \to Z$ or $+:R\times R \to R$, not $+:Z \times Z \to R$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by using properties of real numbers although there may be other approaches. Also we use the fact that there exist no intger between $0$ and $1$.

Suppose $p_i \ne \pm 1$ then we must have $\vert p_i \vert > 1$. Then using the properties of real numbers we have
$$ 1 =  \vert (k-b)p_i \vert  > \vert (k -b) \vert \ge 0$$
So $\vert k-b\vert$ is a integer less than $1$ but greater than equal to $0$. Clearly $k-b \ne 0$ and since there are no integers between $0$ and $1$ we have contradiction. So we have $0 \le |p_i| \le 1$. Since $p_i \ne 0$ we must have $\vert p_i \vert = 1$by which we conclude that $p_i = \pm 1$

Comment: Thank you, that explains it!